# Can CPU intensive apps cause sudden shutdowns?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, battery, power-on

Lately my Droid Incredible has been shutting down spontaneously when using my GPS for periods over 30 or 45 minutes.  After the shutdown the back of the phone is pretty hot (and that's with a case on it).  I kept my other services to a bare minimum when using the GPS.

Could this be a battery overdraw (or overload with it connected to a charger)? If not, could some services (GPS, CPU-intensive games/apps, etc) or a combo of services cause the CPU to overheat and shutdown (much like a laptop when it gets too hot when the CPU is overworked with no additional cooling)?

Comment: It sounds like overheating, for sure.

Comment: GPS navigation is an intensive activity, it is charging, uses GPU to render 3D graphics, 3G antenna for downloading map data, the screen is never turned off, and the GPS module is active. While GPS navigating all those heat producing activity happens together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes

Overworking the CPU is what creates the intense heat, this intense heat is detected by the OS and shutdowns the phone to protect your hardware. (A PC works just the same).